# Why my constructor not getting called

Tags: c++, oop

```
Class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
       cout << "constructor called";
    }
};

int main()
{
  A obj;     // constructor getting called
  A obj1();   // constructor not getting called
}
```

When i instantiate **obj** object , my constructor getting called.
But when i instantiate **obj1** , my constructor not getting called.

I would like to know the reason for it.

Comment: Because you declare `obj1` as a *function*, taking no arguments and returning an `A` object.

Comment: You might search "most vexing parse" for more infos.

Answer (score 0):

`A obj1();` actually does not create any object, it's a function declaration.

`()` should be avoided here as the compiler can't tell if you meant to create a `A` object or declare a `obj1` function returning a `A` object.